# Display Next 15 days excluding sunday in php

Tags: php, laravel

How to Display Next 15 Days Without Saturday, Sunday in PHP. For Next 15 Days I am Using following Code. to Display Next 15 Days

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' day')) ."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if` statement

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    $day = date('D', strtotime('+'.$i.' day'));
    if($day != 'Sun' && $day != 'Sat'){
        echo date('D d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' day')) ."<br />";
    }
}
```